# SQL Like with multiple statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So I have the following query which does not give back the right results and I do not know why:

Sample data:

```
LIST1 | LIST2
APRIL | NOLA
NOLA  | BEBB
NOLA  | APROLS
APRA  | BLIN
```

The query:

```
SELECT LIST1, 
       LIST2, 
       CASE WHEN (([LIST1] LIKE '%APR%' 
                   OR [LIST1] LIKE '%NOLA%') 
             AND ([LIST2] NOT LIKE '%APR%' 
                   AND [LIST2] NOT LIKE '%NOLA%')) 
            THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
       END AS RESULTS
```

It gives back 1 for both rows. It should give back 0 for the first row. So I would expect the following output

```
LIST1 | LIST2 | RESULTS
APRIL | NOLA  | 0
NOLA  | BEBB  | 1
NOLA  | APROLS| 0
APRA  | BLIN  | 1
```

What is my mistake here? The output should be 0 for those two cases as I have clearly put in an 'AND' statement.

Comment: Add some more sample table data and adjust the expected result accordingly. Also explain why you want that result.

Comment: The query looks fine and should give you the expected result. This SQL fiddle proves that: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bc8cf/1

Comment: In my query, the last AND was an OR. Someone edited it and I accepted without seeing it as I probably thought they edited only the format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT LIST1, 
       LIST2, 
       CASE 
          WHEN (([LIST1] LIKE '%APR%' 
                 OR [LIST1] LIKE '%NOLA%') 
           OR ([LIST2] NOT LIKE '%APR%' 
                AND [LIST2] NOT LIKE '%NOLA%')) 
          THEN 1 
          ELSE 0 
       END AS RESULTS

LIST1   LIST2   RESULTS
APRIL   NOLA    1
NOLA    BEBB    1
NOLA    APROLS  1
APRA    BLIN    1
```

it gives you for both case 1 because `[LIST1] LIKE '%APR%' OR [LIST1] LIKE '%NOLA%'` this line is true for 'APRIL' of 1st row value of  list1 
and again it is true for 'NOLA' for 2nd row and when any portion of will true of or condition then full condition will be true. As a result you got both case 1

but if you put `and` condition then result will be as your expectation

```
SELECT LIST1, 
       LIST2, 
       CASE WHEN (
         (
           [LIST1] LIKE '%APR%' 
                   OR [LIST1] LIKE '%NOLA%') 
             AND 
         (
                  [LIST2] NOT LIKE '%APR%' 
                   AND [LIST2] NOT LIKE '%NOLA%')

          ) 
            THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
       END AS RESULTS from t
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9f8c5/1

```
LIST1   LIST2   RESULTS
APRIL   NOLA    0
NOLA    BEBB    1
NOLA    APROLS  0
APRA    BLIN    1
```

Comment: But I also included an 'AND' statement. Does it just disregard it? So what should I change if I would like the desired output?

Comment: @mrPy   http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0d7a4/1  could you check this please does it ok?